# Is there any way of making the customtkinter CTkComboBox only list 5 items at a time with a scroll bar to go through all items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk


window = ctk.CTk()
window.geometry("800*600")


ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")


min_price_dropdown = ctk.CTkComboBox(window, values=["£50,000","£60,000","£70,000","£80,000","£90,000","£100,000","£110,000","£120,000","£125,000","£150,000","£175,000","£200,000","£210,000","£220,000","£225,000","£250,000","£275,000","£300,000","£325,000","£350,000","£375,000","£400,000","£425,000","£450,000","£475,000","£500,000","£525,000","£550,000","£575,000","£600,000","£625,000","£650,000","£675,000","£700,000","£725,000","£750,000","£775,000","£800,000","£825,000","£850,000","£875,000","£900,000","£925,000","£950,000","£975,000","£1,000,000","£2,000,000","£3,000,000","£4,000,000","£5,000,000","£6,000,000","£7,000,000","£8,000,000","£9,000,000","£10,000,000","£11,000,000","£12,000,000","£13,000,000","£14,000,000","£15,000,000"], dropdown_hover_color="blue", width=200, border_color="blue")
min_price_dropdown.pack()
min_price_dropdown.set("Minimum Price")

window.mainloop()
```

I only want 5 items appearing at a time with a scroll wheel to go through all of the prices

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.html) I don't think it is possible to alter the amount of items that are shown on *popup*. You might consider coding it from scratch.

Comment: how would that even be done

Comment: with a little bit of math and effort, tkinter let's you do this. The combobox can be split into single parts an Entry, a Button and a popup window with a scrollbar where labels are shown.

Comment: There is already a solution. https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues/1990